# Ubuntu 21.04 freezes

Tags: restart

My Ubuntu 21.04 works OK after every booting & rebooting. Yet after 3-4 hours, it “freezes”. Nothing helps but force restart. How to avoid the latter?

The Terminal runs:

```
<free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.5Gi       2.2Gi       243Mi       278Mi       1.1Gi       832Mi
Swap:         2.0Gi        17Mi       2.0Gi

vm.swappiness = 60

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 17772   -2

top - 09:32:34 up 26 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.26, 0.59, 1.18
Tasks: 203 total,   3 running, 200 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 42.9 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 57.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0top - 09:33:54 up 27 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.72, 0.73, 1.18
Tasks: 203 total,   3 running, 200 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 25.0 us, 18.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 56.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si, top - 09:33:54 up 27 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.72, 0.73, 1.18
Tasks: 203 total,   4 running, 199 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 40.0 us, 20.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 40.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,top - 09:33:54 up 27 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.72, 0.73, 1.18
Tasks: 203 total,   2 running, 201 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 33.3 us, 33.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 33.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,top - 09:33:54 up 27 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.72, 0.73, 1.18
Tasks: 203 total,   5 running, 198 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 28.6 us, 42.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 28.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,
MiB Mem :   3623.3 total,    139.9 free,   2286.0 used,   1197.4 buff/c
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2029.4 free,     18.6 used.    822.0 avail> 


# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=28539ebd-a6e3-4fa7-8dcc-8bdc31b0f505 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw
```

---

To begin with, the most valuable stuff should be on a hard disc (e.g., Transcend) and that daily amended (having the Internet off). Keep the installation tool ready too. When freezing is bad and the advice is nowhere to get, then force switch off, plug in the installation tool, boot up while pressing F2. From a boot menu, chose the above tool and reinstall the system. Prefer the LTS version. Mind Livepatch. That worked in my case.

Comment: Can you provide you model? I had similar problem on laptop Lenovo legion 5i and resolved this by downgrade to 20.04LTS and upgrade drivers, maybe it gonna help (if same model)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my English is not native lang. I mean device type like computer model

Comment: Probably an easy fix. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s` and `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks. I copied what the Terminal ran. What is <@heynnema>? Please translate for the dummy. I saw your good profile -- no "messages" or so.

Comment: @Eugene Look at the example of this comment. The "@heynnema" will notify me that you've left me a comment. Do the commands that I requested, and edit that output into your question for me to look at. Then I can try to solve your problem.

Comment: @Eugene I had the same trouble with Xubuntu 21.04. The workaround I found is to install the mainline Linux kernel 5.14.1 as described here: https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you. Sudo ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough RAM, or enough swap.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.5Gi       2.2Gi       243Mi       278Mi       1.1Gi       832Mi
Swap:         2.0Gi        17Mi       2.0Gi
```

We'll increase your swap from 2G to 4G and see if that helps...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

Reinstalled Ubuntu to fix the problem.

Comment: @Eugene I restored the previous edit to your question. The `top` command output is incorrect, but at least the other info is there again. The fstab in the comments is also unreadable, and should also be another edit to your question. Remember to select the pasted text and then click the {} icon to format it. Then delete the prior comment. Thanks. ps: what does `free -h` show now?

Comment: @Eugene Hit control-x to quit pico, but don't save the file when it asks.

Comment: @Eugene Please put `cat /etc/fstab` as an edit to your original question, and then delete the two comments.

Comment: @Eugene Maybe I should have been more clear... type `cat /etc/fstab` in the `terminal`, and put that output into your question, along with another `free -h`.

Comment: @Eugene  Just click on the link, above.

Comment: @Eugene click on "continue this discussion in chat". Type in the bottom window pane.

Comment: @Eugene Status please...

Comment: @Eugene Status please...

Comment: @Eugene Are you still having freezes?

Comment: @Eugene Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `ls -al /var/crash` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @Eugene Do the commands in `terminal`. Copy the output to the clipboard. Edit your question. Paste the clipboard. Select the pasted text and click the {} button to format it into human-readable. Delete the prior 3 comments. Thanks!

Comment: See -- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/my-pc-os-ubuntu-21-04-freezes-daily-4175700445/ -- They have a lot of other ideas. As for <Copy the output to the clipboard. ... Paste the clipboard. Select the pasted text and click the {} button to format it into human-readable> it may take time to find all that stuff.

Comment: @Eugene You haven't deleted your older comments where you tried to paste in command outputs. You haven't given me the info that I asked for two days ago. I can't help you if you don't follow instructions.

Comment: Far as I get it, right now -- memory total = 3.5Gi; memory used = 2.7Gi; memory free = 167Mi; memory shared = 336Mi; memory buff/cache = 687Mi; memory available = 297Mi. Swap total = 5.8Gi; swap used = 1.4Gi; swap free = 4.4Gi.

Comment: My Ubuntu got reinstalled. The matter is over.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for the update. You'll still want to increase your /swapfile to 4G.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. Your every suggestion is welcome. Kindly note, reinstallation was due to a hacker's visit. So, I found myself busy with security. Are there any alternative means for a chat?

Comment: @Eugene  Eventually the system will prompt you to move to chat, or a chat can be manually started, but I don't know how to do that. Reminder to delete your answer, below.

Comment: what link? Please specify.

Comment: <@Eugene Hit control-x to quit pico, but don't save the file when it asks.> -- I will. Just, please, tell me when. Because here, all good comments got mixed up in one sorry mess.

Comment: @Eugene I don't understand your last two comments.

Comment: All comments here got mixed up and it is hard to tell which are the last. Anyway, that's what I addressed to you -- Memory: total=3,5G ; used=1,1G ; free=142M ; shared=287M ; buff/cache=2,3G ; available=1,9G. Swap: total=4,0G ; used=0B ; free=4,0G.